# How to group things together (image over text + Image over text) within a div tag?

Tags: html

Im trying to do something that seems fairly simple.

Im trying to show a couple of images all in a row.  with each image, i want to show text directly under it.  When I try this it either wraps the lines and I can't get the images next to each other OR it does everything inline and the 3rd image wraps the screen.

any thoughts?

here's some code...

```
    <div style"display:inline">
        <img src="img/test.jpg" />
        Features
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wO4HJOf_DGU" rel="lightbox"><img alt="Watch a Video" src="img/test.jpg" /></a>
        Watch a Video
        <img src="img/test.jpg" /><br/>
        Excetera
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap de images in div's. Put the text in a span in the same div; and put it under the image by giving it a  `style="clear:both"`

You can make the div `float` and put them in a bigger div if you don't want to set their width manually.

For example:
`<div>
         <div style="width:100px; height:100px; border: 1px solid red; diaply:inline;"></div>
    <span style="clear:both">Textg</span>
  </div>`

Where the inline `div` acts as image.

The text appears under the image

Comment: Ok.  I wrapped each image in a div tag + added a span tag with the style that you mentioned within the same div.  Then I added the float:left tag to each of the divs.  Now everything is "inline", including the text.  The text is not appearing underneath the images...  Thanks so far...